# T-SQL Update Query to enter recurring data in groups of three

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of data, it is duplicated twice in the same table to make three sets.

Its "ReferenceID" is the primary key, i want to in a way group the 3 same ReferenceID's and inject these three values "f2f" "NF2F" "Travel" into the row called "Type" in any order but ensure that each ReferenceID only has one of those values.

For Example:

```
ReferenceID | Type 
------------|-------

    1          f2f
    1          nf2f
    1          Travel
    2          f2f
    2          nf2f
    2          Travel
    3          f2f
    3          nf2f
    3          Travel
```

etc etc...

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `row_number` that you `mod` by the number of groups you have (in your case 3):

```
declare @t table(RefType varchar(10));
insert into @t values ('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel'),('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel'),('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel');

select (row_number() over (order by RefType) % 3) + 1 as ReferenceID
    ,RefType
from @t
order by ReferenceID
        ,RefType;
```

## Output

```
+-------------+---------+
| ReferenceID | RefType |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 | f2f     |
|           1 | nf2f    |
|           1 | Travel  |
|           2 | f2f     |
|           2 | nf2f    |
|           2 | Travel  |
|           3 | f2f     |
|           3 | nf2f    |
|           3 | Travel  |
+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to keep inserting until it has done all the rows. If the number of rows can vary from month to month

Comment: Bravo for understanding the question I can't and still don't get it.

Comment: @microchef I am not sure what you mean?  This will give you an incrementing number for each value of the entire dataset.  If you only want to apply this to new data, find the max `ReferenceID` and then add it on to the result of this query to ensure a unique key value.